# what does this.id return?

Tags: javascript

```
function test(){
alert(this);//alerts oblect
alert(this.id);//alerts undefined

}

<input type="text" onKeyPress="test();" id="text1">
```

why does alert(this.id) alert **undefined**? Is this because ***this*** returns the **document** object?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be.

```
function test(objRef){
  alert(objRef);//alerts oblect
  alert(objRef.id);//alerts undefined
}

<input type="text" onKeyPress="test(this);" id="txtNum" />
```

EDIT: You may use following code too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var txtnum = document.getElementById("txtNum");
            txtnum.onkeypress = function() {
                alert(this);
                alert(this.id);
            };
        };
 </script>

 <input type="text" id="txtNum" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,i knew that. but is there a way to know form which object that function was triggered? in this case i need to to know if the function was called from text1's keypress event.

Comment: `<input type="text" onKeyPress="test();">` has no `id`. Maybe we should add it too on the markup.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the window instance. Try it in your browser:

```
javascript:alert(this)
```

I get an `[object Window]`

Answer (score 0):

In global scope the context (this) is windows, since window have no property called "id" its undefined.